# Testing the rewrite module

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can I check whether the rewrite engine is active on my server?

Comment: Please clarify - programmatically or in your httpd.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/? [L,R]
```

This will redirect any request to `http://example.com/`.

Comment: +1 Yup. If nothing happens at all, `.htaccess` files aren't being parsed. If it throws a 500, the rewrite module is probably not activated. If you get redirected to example.com, it works.